# Xtext editor with pages

Tags: xtext

I want to edit the XtextEditor so it will contain multiple pages.

I tried to create a class that extends MultiPageEditorPart and implements IResourceChangeListener and within it to create XtextEditor as the first page.

but when i run it, there is null pointer exception on setDocumentProvider(documentProvider.get()).
I don't know where it is should be initialized.

so my question is whether i should continue with this path of solution? (if so how to fix my issue) or what is the best solution?

Comment: I found a solution, hope it will help.
i made eclipse create the class and initiate it properly.

IConfigurationElement[] configs = Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getConfigurationElementsFor("org.eclipse.ui.editors");
for(IConfigurationElement currentConfElement : configs) {
  if(currentConfElement.getAttribute("id").equals(<TextEditor id>)) { 
    try {
      editor = (XtextEditor) currentConfElement.createExecutableExtension("class");
    } catch (CoreException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  break;
  }
}